# When I am installing Atom IDE it is not working and I get a blank screen

Tags: ide, atom-editor

When I tried to install atom from atom.io version 1.48.0. I downloaded a file of 175.8 MB and when I installed it everything went smoothly. But when atom launched I can see anything but a white space with atom explorer. I have attached a photo please have a look at it. I even tried older versions. No progress same error. I think there is problem with my PC. I have used atom(older version) in the past on the same PC. Looking for help, For image click here [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W3n7.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are currently in the developer tools window. To exit developer window press

> **ctrl+shift+I**

To know more about atom shortcuts read the documentation. [atom shortcuts Documentation](https://atom.io/packages/atom-shortcuts)